# Why Android Volley doesn't work first time?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

While the Log.d always show the string(first time too), the boolean only being seated the second time or more that I do the request. I want the first time the boolean is true.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_UPDATE,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //do stuffs with response of post
                    Log.d("Bien:",response.substring(0));
                    correctoExterna = true;
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //do stuffs with response erroe
                    correctoExterna = false;
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("consulta",consultaExterna);
            return params;
        }

    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    if(correctoExterna) snackBar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is asynchronous which means your `correctoExterna` hasn't change yet since the callback did not fire yet. If you need to implement in a synchronous manner use `FutureRequest`

```
RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_UPDATE, future, future){
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("consulta",consultaExterna);
        return params;
    }
};
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
requestQueue.add(request);

try {
  String response = future.get(); 
  Log.d("Bien:",response.substring(0));
  correctoExterna = true;
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
  correctoExterna = false;
}

if(correctoExterna) snackBar();
```

Comment: Thanks @Enzokie your reply works fine with Asynctask + an interface. Thank you very much.
Now I need with JsonObjectRequest and I have problems with params, the response always send wrong message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to put "if(correctoExterna) snackBar();"
in "public void onResponse(String response)" and behind the "correctoExterna = true;"

After you add StringRequest in RequestQueue,it will execute on background thread,so when you execute "if(correctoExterna) snackBar();",it may not call onResponse callback method.